# Getting a list of tickets based on a particular project using Fogbugz API

Tags: php, fogbugz, fogbugz-api

I'm wanting to list all tickets of a certain project using the Fogbugz API. I have the FogBugz project ID and name, now im not too sure how to get the tickets for the project.

I've looked on their API docs and unable to find this option, does anybody know how you are able to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you just use the search function:

```
https://your.fogbugz.com/api.asp?token=yourtoken&cmd=search&q=project:myproject&cols=sTitle,sPersonAssignedTo
```

You can also use `q=project:"=12"+status:active` where 12 is the project ID.

**edit** that should do it.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for this, however do you know how to get only cases that are of 'Active' status of a particular project? Thanks in advance